# Spotify API Works Sometimes, Stalls Other Times(?)

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to follow along in a simple tutorial that uses the spotipy api. The code is below:

```
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy
import sys
from pprint import pprint
import spotipy
import yaml
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from data_functions import offset_api_limit, get_artists_df, get_tracks_df, get_track_audio_df,\
    get_all_playlist_tracks_df, find_popular_album, get_recommendations_artists, get_recommendations_tracks, get_most_popular_artist,  get_recommendations_genre
import pandas as pd

urn = 'spotify:artist:3jOstUTkEu2JkjvRdBA5Gu'

scope = "user-library-read user-follow-read user-top-read playlist-read-private"
with open("spotify/spotify_info.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    spotify_details = yaml.safe_load(stream)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(
    client_id=spotify_details['client_id'],
    client_secret=spotify_details['client_secret'],
    redirect_uri=spotify_details['redirect_uri'],
    scope=scope,
))

results = sp.search(q='album:' + 'From 2 to 3', type='album')
print(results)
print("\n\n")
items = results['albums']['items']
if len(items) > 0:
    print(items)
    album = items[0]
    print(album)
    print(album['name'], album['id'])

alb = sp.album(album['id']) #issues here 
pprint(alb)
```

The code works and pulls the information from spotify until the marked line. I have no idea what's different about this function but when it hits that line it stalls indefinitely. Has anyone encountered this issue?

I've tried changing my authentication configuration and various functions such as albums, related_artists that also don't work.

Comment: It is having some specific issue during program some error or anything.

Comment: Why fo you do `alb = sp.album(album['id'])` outside the `if len(items) > 0:`, and not inside?